# Divergence of N particles

Tags: simulation, physics

I have a set of N particles with properties like position (`x`, `y`, `z`), velocities (`vx`, `vy`, `vz`), and mass. Given only these information, is it possible to compute the divergence of velocity of this system? If yes, how can I do this?

(Apologies for the bad formatting as I'm new to asking question here, thank you !)

Comment: What is your definition of divergence of velocity of N particles? Do the particles interact with each other vie some force, like gravitational force, Coulomb electrical interaction force or Lennard-Jones potential force?

Comment: @Futurologist in my case the particles interact via gravity only. I want to do calculate div.v to show whether these particles are converging/diverging, i.e. whether div.v is bigger or smaller than 0.

Comment: Again, what is your definition of divergence. For a smooth vector field defined at every point in three space, the divergence is the sum of the appropriate partial derivatives of the three components of the field. In your case, you have a bunch of velocity vectors at a finite number of points in space, so definitely not a smooth vector field. How do you define the discrete analogue of divergence for your finitely many velocities in space?

Comment: @Futurologist what you said makes sense - my particles are not a smooth approximation of vector field so I can't really define divergence. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could find a way to define a discrete version of divergence, but there could be various ways to define discrete divergence. That is why I was asking you, if you had a specific construciton in mind. But why do you need divergence? What is your goal? Since the interaction is gravitational, you are not modelling some gas or fluid, where divergence might be meaningful.